# How to dynamically chain another filter to an existing queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is my views for a store page that displays items for sale.  The items shown are filtered by the users zipcode OR most popular items.  There are also links to filter by pants, shirts, etc.  The links use AJAX to return the querysets.

The problem with my code is that clicking 'pants' for example, returns the queryset for just pants, but does not filter by zipcode.  I COULD filter by both, but then issue becomes what if the user clicks 'filter by most popular items' rather than zipcode?  How would I return a queryset for pants and most popular items?

```
def storefront(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.my_profile.zipcode:
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode=user.zip).order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}        
        else:
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
    else:
        latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
        context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries} 
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'shirts':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=1)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'pants':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=2)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'shoes':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)

    return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

To clarify the issue:

From the end users point of view there two filters.  'zipcode'/'popular items' and 'shirts'/'pants'/'shoes'.  Currently, if the end user changes filter 2, it does not keep the results of filter 1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `filter()` method on a queryset again so there is no problem to chain filters just like this:

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode=user.zip)
...
if request.GET.get('filter') == 'shirts':
    latest_entries = latest_entries.filter(entrytype=1)
```

Comment: This is helpful I guess but still doesn't resolve my issue.  Because filtering shirts does not remember whether 'zipcode' or 'popular' was initially selected.